# How can I find all resources that can access an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket, and I want to know which AWS resources have permission to access it (security audit). There is nothing in the bucket policy itself - permissions are defined using IAM policies on the resources.

I have a LOT of different components on this project. Is there a way to find all the resources that have permissions for this bucket? Or do I have to check the IAM policies on every single resource in the account?

Comment: There is no way to know, no. You need to check each role / user / group / policy but know that policies can basically get arbitrarily complex, wether or not access is allowed can additionally depend on the time of day, the requesting ip address, the cognito id, etc. AWS IAM in general cannot answer "who can do X?" or "what can role Y do?", it can only answer "can X do Y?"

Comment: I am looking to answer this question, as well. I will post anything relevant if I find it.

Comment: I agree this is really though to do - keep in mind there are a lot of things you have to consider other than just the IAM policies and resource based policies (for example, you have to look at permission boundaries and service control policies that apply to the principals) 

This series of articles my colleague wrote on the topic might help you out: 
https://ermetic.com/whats-new/blog/cloud-security/the-challenges-of-securing-data-access-in-the-cloud-part-1/